# Set subscription for an android application for specific time

Tags: android

I have developed a application. i want to make user to subscribe it for one year. After one year i want to disable/uninstall my application automatically.

How can i do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you doing this? It's not very user friendly. Why not just disable any use of the app after a year and let the user uninstall it? That way they at least get to see that it's not expired instead of looking for an app that doesn't exist anymore!

Comment: Yes but how i will come to know that a year has been passed and i need to disable the application?

Comment: Just get the time when they registered and then add a year to it. There are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a paid application, you **should** be able to use the [licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) available on the Android marketplace to do what you require. It will not uninstall the application but it should be able to disable it.

edit: However, I don't have enough experience with the licensing to know if uninstalling and reinstalling the app will reset the time period or if there is any way to allow reinstalls. It may be worth experimenting with though.